# Can't access JSON file exists in the same folder : AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I try to use a JSON file, JSON file exists in the same folder with my HTML file.

```
<html ng-app="countryApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
      countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
        $http.get('countries.json').success(function(data) {
          $scope.countries = data;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="CountryCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Population</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
        <td>{{country.name}}</td>
        <td>{{country.population}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I load my HTML file I get a console error saying:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://countries.json/. Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can't load other files from your javascript on localhost, due to security issues. Try running your page in http server.

If you have python you can just write `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` in your console where working directory is your source folder and then open http://localhost:8000 .

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is change `$http.get('countries.json').success(function(data) {`  to this

```
$http.get("http://localhost:9009/yourFolderName/countries.json").then(function (data) {
```

assuming you are running http local server on port 9009.